# What Size Heat Shrink Tubing for Splicing Lamp Wire (SPT-2 18-2 AWG)?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cabling, splicing

I am splicing some lamp cables.  The cable is SPT-2 18-2 lamp wire.  First I will be using some vinyl insulated butt splices rated for 22-18 AWG and 600v to make the connection.  Then, I want to cover the splices with heat shrink tubing.  I'm having a hard time finding definitive results on what size tubing to use, though I am inferring from various sources that it's probably 3/4" polyolefin tubing that I need.  Can anyone confirm or deny this, or otherwise make a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be splicing lamp wires outside the fixture or lamp. If you need to splice in the middle of a run you should replace the cord.

Inside a fixture or lamp no heat shrink is required or needed.

Heat shrink tubing just needs to fit over the area to be covered before shrinking.

> **Article 400 Flexible Cords and Cables**
>
> **400.9 Splices**
>
> Flexible cord shall be used only in continuous lengths without splice
>   or tap where initially installed in applications permitted by
>   400.7(A). The repair of hard-service cord and junior hard-service cord (see Trade Name column in Table 400.4) 14 AWG and larger shall be
>   permitted if conductors are spliced in accordance with 110.14(B) and
>   the completed splice retains the insulation, outer sheath properties,
>   and usage characteristics of the cord being spliced.

Comment: Why do you say I shouldn't splice outside the lamp? Let me give you a bit more detail.  I am interconnecting strip lights which came with short (~2 feet) connector cables.  I need them a bit longer, and I have a roll of the same cable type the connector is made from.  There's no way to put the splice inside the fixture, and I can't find longer cables with the same connector at the end.  My plan was to splice with the butts, then heat shrink, and, if necessary, place the spliced area inside a box or conduit. Is this not enough to be safe?

Comment: I should add, I can ensure the polarity of the connections will remain consistent and that the wires will be insulated from each other.  Beyond all of these things I've mentioned, I'm not sure what concerns there are.

Comment: If its line voltage (120/240v) then splices need to be in a box, fixture or enclosure. Splices should not be in conduit. If this is a setup with factory wiring that comes pre-wired you should not be splicing it at all

Comment: Why the blanket statement of not splicing?  Wiring is wiring, no?  What tangible risks are there if the cable is spliced well and enclosed in a box?  I'm curious about the reason because we both know splices exist all over the place in a home.  I have two identically rated 18-2 cabling that I simply need to join and make as safe as possible.

Comment: i'm sorry if you don't like it, but for NEC (which applies to 120v household wiring) **Speedy is right**.   NEC forbids splicing line cords for appliances outside an electrical box or listed splice device (which don't exist for line cords).   The rules on diy.se is that we give code legal answers, we do not advise infringement simply because it is popular.

Comment: bubbleking, wiring is **not** just wiring. 120v wiring is special.  NEC decides how work is done and whether an insurer pays on a fire claim (and which: homeowner or contractor), or you get stuck owing $300,000 on a pile of ashes.  It matters to a lot of people, hence the standard.   Like I say: 120v is special.

Comment: @Harper, thank you for the support, but I am done here. I quickly realized the OP is simply another one looking for only the answers they want to hear.

Comment: @Harper - Contrary to what this stranger is assuming about me after providing virtually no information, your information has been quite helpful and I won't be attempting my original plan.  It's not that I don't like it, it's that when I ask a question, I am looking for explanation because I want to understand the reasoning behind the advice.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - I'm sorry if you inferred otherwise, but I am not just looking for someone to tell me I can do what I want. Finding out the WHY of something is a big part of my learning process. I started another question because the issues you brought up were outside the scope of tubing. I wanted to know if *and why* the procedure is unsafe and what *alternative* procedure might exist. A statement like "If this is a setup with factory wiring that comes pre-wired you should not be splicing it at all" with no further explanation is akin to the parental "because I said so." It's fine if you...

Comment: ... don't want to spend time explaining, but this will decrease the usefulness of the answer and beckon for more questions. It is unfair for you to assume these additional questions imply that I don't believe you. Maybe you come across that a lot on here, but that's not me. I merely want to learn by understanding. And when my approach is flawed, I want to understand how to formulate a different, better approach.

Comment: For better or worse, SE decided "diy" means home improvement.  Remember when you first saw a big-box home improvement store's electrical aisle and thought to yourself "Well this is nothing like Radio Shack.  They don't even sell resistors here! This barely rates the name 'electrical'!"  ... Same difference between electronics.se and diy.  The bright red line is the Electrical Code. This world is about compliance not invention. Speedy should at least give you NEC citations showing why your splice is not legal.

Comment: @Harper -Indeed. When I asked this first question, I was under the assumption all of this was legal (why do they sell butt splices and heat shrink tubes if you can't use them?). My question didn't initially concern safety or legality. I just wanted to buy the correct tubing. Speedy's comments made me realize that I had code issues to address, as well.  At that point I needed to know why it was illegal and how to accomplish the same thing legally. I figured maybe there was no way to do it, but I held out hope that someone could explain the right way, if one existed. My other question solved it.

Comment: Good question.  "They" sell butt splices for automotive, prototyping and hobby use.  By "they" I mean auto parts, generalist hardware stores and big-box stores who compete with same, which is why they show up at Home Depot.   A proper electrical supply house would not have them in their shop; they'd only stock variants built to the higher standard of code electrical, which require different crimp tools.

Comment: I must take the above back!   I checked with Gardner-Bender.  They do claim their common automotive-grade crimp terminals are UL listed for code electrical work, citing this: http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/showpage.html?&name=ZMVV.GuideInfo&ccnshorttitle=Wire+Connectors+and+Soldering+Lugs&objid=1074134836&cfgid=1073741824&version=versionless&parent_id=1073996457&sequence=1

Comment: How does one splice something in accordance with 110.14(B) ? This answer is useful, but fails to mention what type of shrink tube, "retains the insulation, outer sheath properties, and usage characteristics of the cord being spliced."