# Safest Way to Contain Spliced Lamp Cord

Tags: electrical, wiring, cabling, splicing

I am interconnecting some strip lights in a closet.  They are linkable LED fixtures which each come with a connector cable to link, optionally, to additional fixtures.  The connector cables are a bit short for what I have in mind, but I need to use their ends because they have special connectors to link the fixtures and maintain correct polarity.

The connector cables are 18-2 SPT-2 lamp cord.  I have a spool of the same type of cable.  I am planning to cut the connector cable in the middle and insert an appropriate extension length from my spool.  My plan is to splice them using some 22-18 butt splices, then heat shrink them with 3/4" tubing.  I will ensure the splices are solid and the polarity is correct.  Beyond this, what should I do to make sure this setup is safe?

None of this will be behind a wall.  The strips will be against the wall, on their mounting brackets, and the cabling can be secured however.  If nothing else, I'll just be using cable staples.  I could also run all or some of the cabling through conduits, bracketed against the wall.  Or I could simple put the spliced areas within junction boxes.  Any suggestions for the safest way to do this are welcome.

I realize there may not be a code-approved way of doing this.  The cables will not be in a place where they can be routinely touched, and if I were to move out of the house, I would take all of this stuff down, except for the first of the linkable fixtures which was installed with a junction box by an electrician (it is controlled by a light switch).

If you believe there is no way this can be done without a moderate risk of fire, it would be very helpful to hear why you think so.

**Update:** This particular line of products now has longer lengths of linking cords available.  As a result, no splicing needs to be attempted.

EDIT: This is obviously NOT a duplicate question as erroneously suggested as "What size heat shrink tube is required?" and "How can I safely do something?" are completely different questions.

Comment: are these low voltage or 120V?

Comment: @bib - The power comes off a circuit in the wall and runs into this junction box: http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Direct-Wire-Linkable-Junction-Box-32612/100384851     which connects the first fixture.  The additional fixtures I'm installing would be run from that first fixture's connector jack.  The first fixture is this:  http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-36-in-Premium-LED-Linkable-Under-Cabinet-Light-29665/206166478    I am having trouble determining if the output from that GE junction box is considered low voltage, but as it's meant to run these strips, I would think it is.

Comment: The fixtures you list are 120V. Any interconnected wiring will also be 120V.

Comment: These are 120V fixtures. Why not use multiple linkable junction boxes on each end of  the longer runs and use standard NM-B cable between the boxes?

Comment: @bib - So you mean like... j-box 1 output from connector using connector cable to connect to same connector jack on j-box 2, then run NM cable from j-box 2 to j-box 3 and then plug a fixture into j-box 3's connector jack?

Comment: @bib - I think maybe this isn't an option because to maintain polarity, each connector cable has one end with 2 pins and one end with 3 pins.  The j-box has an output for the 2 pins. Each fixture has a 3 pin input and 2 pin output to link the next fixture. The third pin is actually empty; it just makes sure cables are connected correctly. I'd have to somehow get twice as many connector cables, then cut off the third (empty) pin and be extremely careful on maintaining polarity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Size Heat Shrink Tubing for Splicing Lamp Wire (SPT-2 18-2 AWG)?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87928/what-size-heat-shrink-tubing-for-splicing-lamp-wire-spt-2-18-2-awg)

Comment: Reminder - Downvoting a question is for when the question is unclear, lacks research or details and will not be valuable to anyone.  Downvoting IS NOT for expressing that you feel I shouldn't attempt the project a question pertains to.  If you feel that way, instead of downvoting, leave an ANSWER that explains WHY this cannot be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This family of lights uses all 120v wiring which means the full weight of NEC applies.  You cannot "freestyle" splices in the manner you are talking, you must use listed products, which those cheapie butt splices probably won't be.  They do exist, but O'Reilly Auto doesn't sell them and they don't use $5 crimp tools either.

So here's how you handle "the cord is too short".   Legally, splices can only be inside junction boxes.  The American gold standard way to splice inside a junction box is with "wire nuts" - for two 18ga. wires I would use the blue or gray ones.  Do not use stabs, they are not rated for 18ga.

If GE sells a **listed** method to attach their special connectors to your lamp cord, go for it.  Otherwise you can only use it between junction boxes, which means 2 junction boxes.  If you want to do it in one junction box, then buy 2 cords long enough to give you 8" slack inside the box, and splice there.

But I have to say: why on earth are you using this family of products? Don't get me wrong, GE's quality is first rate, but why wrestle with 120v products when you can get the same thing in 12v that's much easier to work with.

Also, these prices are way beyond insane, at least 3-4 times what I've seen in quality 12v products.  IKEA has a broad selection of 12v products at sensible prices.  12v makes the products cheaper because they do not need expensive voltage converters in each lamp.    I buy cheap Chinese LED strips for $7 for a 16 foot roll, I mention that only to shake you out of a notion that $60/foot is a normal price for these things.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I hope you don't mind if I pick your brain for how to continue. Firstly, the butt splices are UL listed.  I already owned a wire stripper/crimper tool made for a number of AWG sizes.  However, I can take your word that wire nut splicing is a better idea.  More on that momentarily.

Comment: As to why I chose these products, the short answer is brightness.  The main fixture has over 1000 lumens and I was hoping to flank the lower sides of the closet with 2 strips of 800 lumens each.

Comment: Well you will certainly never have to worry about the units failing.  GE makes good stuff.

Comment: I can entertain the idea of adding junction boxes along the cabling.  Are you saying I should run NM cable out of a knockout in the existing GE junction box, run that to provide power to another GE junction box and plug the lamp into that?

Comment: You could do that, or just extend the lamp style cords. For splicing, any junction box will do as long as it provides appropriate clamping and strain relief for the cords.  I would just grab a common 1-gang metal box and wire clamp that screw into a 1/2" knockout which is correctly rated for that size of line cord. I find the latter by going to a code electrical supply house with a sample and saying "I got this, I need this" and he disappears in the back for a minute and says "here ya go".  They are often much cheaper than the big-box, but sometimes much more expensive.

Comment: Just to be clear about this equipment.  The GE junction box has a connection jack for a (proprietary?) 2 pin connector.  Each strip lamp has a 3-pin input jack and a 2-pin output jack. The output jack is for the optional daisy chaining. Each lamp comes with 2 cable options. One is a standard A/C polarized plug on one end and a 3-pin connector on the other. This allows plugging it directly into an outlet. There is also a short connector cable with 2-pin on one end and 3-pin on the other. The 2-pin goes to the junction box and the 3-pin goes to the lamp. This leaves the other end open to chain.

Comment: Is it legal to run lamp cord between 2 junction boxes, outside of a wall?

Comment: Good point. We are really stretching 400.7 which is the part permitting flexible cords for luminaires.  Not sure that allows for junction boxes enroute in luminaire cabling, but it definitely doesn't allow for splices outside a box.  The edges of the cord should be different: typically one edge will be ribbed and the other not.   Commonly, not universally, ribbed is neutral.  If there are only 2 pins, they are not conveying ground and are only using the 3rd pin for keying.

Comment: So just to be clear, it would be okay to slice the connector cable in half, feed one half into the j-box, splice it to longer cable inside there, then run the longer cable to another j-box and splice it to the other half of the proprietary connector cable?

Comment: Yeah, that's a question for the code lawyers: I argue yes since it is only to extend wiring to luminaires.  The more fundamental issue is that when things get complicated and ugly like this, that's God trying to give you a hint.  It seems fairly obvious GE hasn't thought this product through, or HoDepo fails to stock key parts of it (which happens to me *every time* I try to use a proprietary system of products from them).  Try other vendors for the length of cable you need, or couplers.  Or exploit their rather good return policies on the kaboodle.

Comment: Ultimately I think my best course of action is to put one of the proprietary j-boxes next to each fixture and wire them in series off the first j-box.  I will just need to investigate if the cubic volume of the box is sufficient for the splices, and what treatment is required for the cabling between the boxes (conduit? staples?).  This way I don't have to cut the proprietary connector cables at all.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  It just boggles my mind that GE doesn't sell couplers or interconnecting cords longer than 2 feet.  I suspect they do, and Big Orange does not. My DIY effectiveness dramatically improved when I stopped shopping there.   Big Orange and Blue overprice, knowing you don't know where else to buy building supplies.

Comment: I've read that GE has fielded numerous requests for longer connectors and that they are "working on it." Maybe, if they finished, a less prominent dealer than the big boxes would have them?

Comment: Looks like they will be releasing more lengths soon.  Check out the manufacturer response on the review at the bottom:
https://byjasco.com/products/under-cabinet-light-fixture-linking-cord

I think I'll just put this on hold until these connectors are released.